# Parts of a .click() function not working together

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, click

I have a simple function, like this:

```
$('.lightbox_trigger').click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($(this).height() * 0.5) + $(this).offset().top - ($(window).height() / 2)}, 500);
  $('#lightbox').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

The idea is, when you click on the lightbox_trigger class you scroll that image to the middle of the page (part 1) and you fade in the lightbox (part 2).

Except I seem to be getting a really weird conflict between parts 1 and 2 of this function. If I remove the `$('#lightbox').fadeIn("slow");` everything works as expected. However, as soon as I add that, it only works the first time - i.e. the time that the the lightbox is faded in. Once the lightbox is visible, the scrolling animation no longer works on click.

Any thoughts?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. The lightbox itself covers the lightbox_trigger images, obviously preventing the click function from taking place.

So, either I can add a `pointer-events: none;` class to the CSS for #lightbox (http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/) or I can change the #lightbox div so as to not cover over the triggers (i.e. changing the z-index, width etc).